# is connection less mode need more overhead?

Tags: networking, header, udp, connection, packets

[image]

the source of Wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_switching) is saying like connectionless mode of protocols might need **complete addressing information**. getting much more information is needed in the packet header for connection less(like udp),but why the header size of UDP is less than TCP ?. Thanks for anwer in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> the source of Wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_switching) is saying like connectionless mode of protocols might need complete addressing information.

It's poorly written, and I will fix it when I have time, but it is really saying that *packet-switching* protocols need more header information than *virtual-circuit* protocols. Unfortunately it is conflating the network layer with the transport layer. IP is a packet-switching network layer protocol, and UDP and TCP are both transport-layer protocols over IP, so they inherit their behaviour from it. *At the transport layer level,* UDP is connectionless and TCP is connection-oriented, but this is out of scope of the quotation you provided.

> why the header size of UDP is less than TCP ?. Thanks for anwer in advance.

The fact that UDP's header size is less than TCP's is because is a simpler protocol that needs less header space: that's all there is to it. Both are designed for packet-switch networks. Virtual circuitry has nothing to do with it.